# Replace token in a file with any content

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd

As a final result I want to copy several lines of text from file `input.html` to `output.html`.

***input.html***

```
 <body>
   <h1>Input File</h1>
   <!-- START:TEMPLATES -->
   <div>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum &amp; Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <span>Path: /home/users/abc.txt</span>
   </div>
   <!-- END:TEMPLATES -->
 <body>
```

***template.html***

```
 <body>
   <h1>Template File</h1>
   <!-- INSERT:TEMPLATES -->
   <p>This is a Text with &nbsp; &amp; /</p>
 <body>
```

I tried different things in `Powershell` and `Bash` to get this work done. But not with success.

Getting the input into a variable is successfuly done by:

```
content="$(sed -e '/BEGIN:TEMPLATES/,/END:TEMPLATES/!d' input.html)"`
```

But to replace in another file is impossible. I tried `sed` and `awk`. Both habe a lot of problems if the variable contains any special character like `&` `/`, ...

***output.html***

```
 <body>
   <h1>Output File</h1>
   <div>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum &amp; Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <span>Path: /home/users/abc.txt</span>
   </div>
   <p>This is a Text with &nbsp; &amp; /</p>
 <body>
```

Thank you for any inputs that helps solving my problem.

Comment: Bash or PowerShell?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Preferred in Powershell. But it's easy to build on a Linux machine, so if you have a bash solution, then I will go with that one.

Comment: Shell scripting sounds just like the wrong tool for templating markup languages like HTML. There are plenty of better template engines in a variety of languages, even the historical Apache's server-side includes would do a better job.

Answer (score 1):

If the START/END comments are on separate lines I'd build a simple parser for the input file like this:

```
$inTemplate = $false
$template = switch -Wildcard -File '.\input.html' {
  '*<!-- START:TEMPLATES -->*'{
    $inTemplate = $true
  }
  '*<!-- END:TEMPLATES -->*'{
    $inTemplate = $false
  }
  default{
    if($inTemplate){
      $_
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can do the same thing for the template file:

```
$output = switch -Wildcard -File '.\template.html' {
  '*<!-- INSERT:TEMPLATES -->*'{
    # return our template input
    $template
  }
  default{
    # otherwise return the input string as is
    $_
  }
}

# output to file
$output |Set-Content output.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with awk.

get all line from file `input.html` between `<!-- START:TEMPLATES -->` and `<!-- END:TEMPLATES -->` stored it in an array `insert_var`.

In `END` section get `template.html` printed line by line in while loop. If line contain `<!-- INSERT:TEMPLATES -->` then print contents of array `insert_var`.

The output get redirected to `output.html`

As far as I know awk not messing with those special characters.

```
awk -v temp_file="template.html" '

BEGIN{input_line_num=1} 

/<!-- END:TEMPLATES -->/{linestart=0}
{ if(( linestart >= 1)) {insert_var[input_line_num]=$0; input_line_num++}}
/<!-- START:TEMPLATES -->/{linestart=1} 

END{ while ((getline<temp_file) > 0) 
    {if (( $0 ~ "<!-- INSERT:TEMPLATES -->")) 
        {for ( i = 1;i < input_line_num; i++) {print insert_var[i]}} 
    else { print } }}
' input.html > output.html
```